# Displaying active filters in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I need a way to get a list of the currently active filters when anything changes, for display on the top of the chart.

Is there way to:

1) Respond to changes in filters?
2) Iterate through all the charts and make a list of the active filters on each?

Comment: [Cross posting with answer by the author here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/dc-js-user-group/aS5BkwFoAbM/C0T5OHnYCAAJ)